# ASP.Net MVC 3 action not called from Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web Application. One of my Razor Views contains a few Textboxes and a Drop Down List. When the User selects an option from the Drop Down List, the following JQuery code executes

**View**

```
<select id="myDDL">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">F1</option>
    <option value="2">F2</option>
    <option value="3">ST1</option>
    <option value="4">ST2</option>
</select>

<div id="someDivToLoadContentTo">

</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#myDDL").change(ChangeEventOfDDL);

function ChangeEventOfDDL(){
var dropDownValue = $('#myDDL').val();
//alert(dropDownValue);
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
       url: '@Url.Action("SomePartialView","testAjax")',
       data: {
           id: dropDownValue
       },
       success: function(data) {
             $('#someDivToLoadContentTo').html(data);
       }
    });
}

});
```

**Controller**

```
public class testAjaxController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult SomePartialView(int id)
    {
        var test = "Hello World";

        return View(test);
    }
}
```

However, when I put a breakpoint on the **SomePartialView** method within the **testAjax** Controller it never gets hit.

Can anyone perhaps suggest why this is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I added the errorData line to my Ajax call like so, but that doesn't seem to give me anything either

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#myDDL").change(ChangeEventOfDDL);

function ChangeEventOfDDL(){
var dropDownValue = $('#myDDL').val();
//alert(dropDownValue);
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
       url: '@Url.Action("SomePartialView","testAjax")',
       data: {
           id: dropDownValue
       },
       success: function(data) {
             $('#someDivToLoadContentTo').html(data);
       },
       error: function (errorData) { $('#someDivToLoadContentTo').html(errorData); }
    });
}

});
```

Comment: What happens if you add [HttpGet] just above your action?

Comment: Are you positive the result(s) aren't cached? Also, depending on your browser, use the debugging tools available to determine that the browser is making (or attempting to make) an external call.

Comment: Yeah if you are running Firebug in Firefox. Open the Net tab and see what it tries to do when you press you change the drop down

Comment: @GazWinter I added the [HttpGet], but it still doesn't reach the action

Comment: The alert you have commented out, does that fire when uncommented?

Comment: Could you add an error detection in the ajax call and see what it says? `error: function (errorData) { $('#someDivToLoadContentTo').html(errorData); }`

Comment: @GazWinter Yes, when the alert is uncommented, it fires

Comment: @GazWinter I ran FireBug and Opened the Net tab, selected an option from the drop down and it came back with an Internal Server Error. http://localhost:56354/testAjax/@Url.Action(%22SomePartialView%22,%22testAjax%22)?id=2

Comment: Look at the URL you posted, its not generating your URL properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks the problem was with the following line

```
url: '@Url.Action("SomePartialView","testAjax")'
```

This was creating an incorrect URL, therefore, the action never got called. I changed to the following line which then corrected the problem

```
url: '/testAjax/SomePartialView/' + dropDownValue
```

Comment: Ah so i did spot the problem in the end :D Although you should be able to do it your way as well. I have it like that on some of my pages...

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to send a value to the Controller you need to use `POST`, not `GET`.

```
type: "POST"
```

Comment: doh! Cannot believe i didnt spot that either.

Answer (score 1):

I think i might have spotted it:

Try changing this:

```
 data: {
       id: dropDownValue
   },
```

to this:

```
 data: {
       'id': dropDownValue
   },
```

Currently i think it might be confused that id doesnt relate to anything.